# Download ZIP, Extract it and Show the images file but not load from Document Directory?

Tags: flutter, dart

Hello friend I am creating project when user install my app  first they download zip file from internet and extract all file inside it then show in my app  but problem is that when user download and extracted file the image inside zip shown in app when I close app and reopen it again image not load from Document directory everytime they need click on download button then show the image  in the app any one tell me what's issue here is code?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:archive/archive.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
 
class DownloadAssetsDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  DownloadAssetsDemo() : super();
 
  final String title = "Download & Extract ZIP Demo";
 
  @override
  DownloadAssetsDemoState createState() => DownloadAssetsDemoState();
}
 
class DownloadAssetsDemoState extends State<DownloadAssetsDemo> {
  //
  bool _downloading;
  String _dir;
  List<String> _images, _tempImages;
  String _zipPath = 'https://coderzheaven.com/youtube_flutter/images.zip';
  String _localZipFileName = 'images.zip';
 
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _images = List();
    _tempImages = List();
    _downloading = false;
    _initDir();
  }
 
  _initDir() async {
    if (null == _dir) {
      _dir = (await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path;
    }
  }
 
  Future<File> _downloadFile(String url, String fileName) async {
    var req = await http.Client().get(Uri.parse(url));
    var file = File('$_dir/$fileName');
    return file.writeAsBytes(req.bodyBytes);
  }
 
  Future<void> _downloadZip() async {
    setState(() {
      _downloading = true;
    });
 
    _images.clear();
    _tempImages.clear();
 
    var zippedFile = await _downloadFile(_zipPath, _localZipFileName);
    await unarchiveAndSave(zippedFile);
 
    setState(() {
      _images.addAll(_tempImages);
      _downloading = false;
    });
  }
 
  unarchiveAndSave(var zippedFile) async {
    var bytes = zippedFile.readAsBytesSync();
    var archive = ZipDecoder().decodeBytes(bytes);
    for (var file in archive) {
      var fileName = '$_dir/${file.name}';
      if (file.isFile) {
        var outFile = File(fileName);
        //print('File:: ' + outFile.path);
        _tempImages.add(outFile.path);
        outFile = await outFile.create(recursive: true);
        await outFile.writeAsBytes(file.content);
      }
    }
  }
 
  buildList() {
    return Expanded(
      child: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: _images.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return Image.file(
            File(_images[index]),
            fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
 
  progress() {
    return Container(
      width: 25,
      height: 25,
      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 20.0, 10.0, 20.0),
      child: CircularProgressIndicator(
        strokeWidth: 3.0,
        valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.white),
      ),
    );
  }
 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
        actions: <Widget>[
          _downloading ? progress() : Container(),
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.file_download),
            onPressed: () {
              _downloadZip();
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            buildList(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can save and restore `List<String>` with package `SharedPreferences` 
code snippet

```
getHistoryImageList() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      _images = prefs.getStringList("images");
    });
  }
...
Future<void> _downloadZip() async {
    ...
    await unarchiveAndSave(zippedFile);

    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.setStringList("images", _tempImages);
    setState(() {
      _images = List<String>.from(_tempImages);
      _downloading = false;
    });
  }
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:archive/archive.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class DownloadAssetsDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  DownloadAssetsDemo() : super();

  final String title = "Download & Extract ZIP Demo";

  @override
  DownloadAssetsDemoState createState() => DownloadAssetsDemoState();
}

class DownloadAssetsDemoState extends State<DownloadAssetsDemo> {
  //
  bool _downloading;
  String _dir;
  List<String> _images, _tempImages;
  String _zipPath = 'https://coderzheaven.com/youtube_flutter/images.zip';
  String _localZipFileName = 'images.zip';

  getHistoryImageList() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      _images = prefs.getStringList("images");
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _images = [];
    getHistoryImageList();
    _tempImages = List();
    _downloading = false;
    _initDir();
  }

  _initDir() async {
    if (null == _dir) {
      _dir = (await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path;
      print("init $_dir");
    }
  }

  Future<File> _downloadFile(String url, String fileName) async {
    var req = await http.Client().get(Uri.parse(url));
    var file = File('$_dir/$fileName');
    print("file.path ${file.path}");
    return file.writeAsBytes(req.bodyBytes);
  }

  Future<void> _downloadZip() async {
    setState(() {
      _downloading = true;
    });

    _images?.clear();
    _tempImages?.clear();

    var zippedFile = await _downloadFile(_zipPath, _localZipFileName);
    await unarchiveAndSave(zippedFile);

    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.setStringList("images", _tempImages);
    setState(() {
      _images = List<String>.from(_tempImages);
      _downloading = false;
    });
  }

  unarchiveAndSave(var zippedFile) async {
    var bytes = zippedFile.readAsBytesSync();
    var archive = ZipDecoder().decodeBytes(bytes);
    for (var file in archive) {
      var fileName = '$_dir/${file.name}';
      print("fileName ${fileName}");
      if (file.isFile && !fileName.contains("__MACOSX")) {
        var outFile = File(fileName);
        //print('File:: ' + outFile.path);
        _tempImages.add(outFile.path);
        outFile = await outFile.create(recursive: true);
        await outFile.writeAsBytes(file.content);
      }
    }
  }

  buildList() {
    return _images == null
        ? Container()
        : Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: _images.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return Image.file(
                  File(_images[index]),
                  fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                );
              },
            ),
          );
  }

  progress() {
    return Container(
      width: 25,
      height: 25,
      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 20.0, 10.0, 20.0),
      child: CircularProgressIndicator(
        strokeWidth: 3.0,
        valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.white),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
        actions: <Widget>[
          _downloading ? progress() : Container(),
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.file_download),
            onPressed: () {
              _downloadZip();
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            buildList(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: DownloadAssetsDemo(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: @ chunhunghan. thanks bro you saved my day it working should used this same code in my music app so user can download zip file extract all music and show in my app only?

Comment: @markanthony, sorry I do not understand your new question clearly. could you post your reproduce code to a new question. thanks.

Comment: I wanna say I want used same code but for music not for images so user download zip file and extract it but zip file have music and they play music in my app is it possible with same code?